# Typo3: Calendar Base (Ext:cal) add Backend and Frontend more 2 img upload options

Tags: calendar, typo3, typoscript, radix, cal

im new in typo3 and need help with ext mod.

I need to include on backend and frontent more 2 options for upload images on Calendar Base Extension ("cal" on TER http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/cal) to show in event view, but the images has to make a relation with the event, so, the upload image is part of the event and i need to put to show this in a defined loacation of template, where i will stylize.

How can i do this?

Sorry for my english.